# JQuery for Image Swap On Hover - Need Simple Adjustment

Tags: jquery, image, hover, swap

Currently I have this JQuery document in my theme's JS folder to allow me to hover over images and swap them to the featured image like so:

http://test.pillarsoflifebook.com/tables/tabletops/wood/rustic-plank-oak/rustic-plank-oak/

```
function myFunction() {
    var $large = jQuery('#largeImage');

    //store the default image as the data src
    $large.data('src', $large.attr('src'));

    var src = jQuery('#largeImage').attr('src');
    jQuery('#thumbs img').hover(function () {
        $large.attr('src', jQuery(this).attr('src').replace('thumb', 'large'));
    }, function () {
        //on mouse leave put back the original value
        $large.attr('src', $large.data('src'));
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(myFunction);
});
```

For another page in my clients site I need the same function WITHOUT the featured image returning to the original. Hence .. when you hover and the featured image changes ... it needs to remain changed when you hover off again.

Should I add another script (pretty much the same with minor adjustments) for this?

Thank you!

Comment: you mean,if you 2nd time hover,It should display 2nd image forever,and not 1st?

Comment: Yes Pratik. It should remain the last image that was swapped. For some of the pages I'll even need a caption or some text data included but I'll save that for another post.

Comment: So your code,after hover effect,placing Dark brown image.and you want last image?

Comment: Pratik, On the current link when you mouse off of an image the original featured image is returned. On a new page ... such as this one ... I want the last image swap to remain. 

http://test.pillarsoflifebook.com/ottomans/

In other words ... I don't want CrissCross to always be the featured image. I want whatever you hover on to replace the featured image and stay there.

Also - I need the featured image to show the dimensions of the specific product. I'm not sure whether to add a caption/data somehow OR to swap to a new image with the dimensions already written in the image file.

Comment: You check my code i posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
function myFunction() {
    var $large = jQuery('#largeImage');

    //store the default image as the data src
    //$large.data('src', $large.attr('src'));

    var src = jQuery('#largeImage').attr('src');
    jQuery('#thumbs img').hover(function () {
        $large.attr('src', jQuery(this).attr('src').replace('thumb', 'large'));
    }, function () {
        //on mouse leave put back the original value
        $large.attr('src', $large.data('src'));
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(myFunction);
});
```

Should i explain?

Comment: The other pages need to work how they currently function though. Should I change the function name and the #largeImage and #thumbs to make this code work on some pages and the others continue how they're working now?

Comment: helo ,i asked is the output you want using Code above?

Comment: And as per your comment ,yes sure.

Comment: Okay I got this to work! I added this: 


function myFunction2() {
    var $large = jQuery('#largeImage1');

    //store the default image as the data src
    $large.data('src', $large.attr('src'));

    var src = jQuery('#largeImage').attr('src');
    jQuery('#thumbs1 img').hover(function () {
        $large.attr('src', jQuery(this).attr('src').replace('thumb', 'large'));
    }, function () {
        //on mouse leave put back the original value
        //$large.attr('src', $large.data('src'));
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(myFunction2);
});

And changed classes.

Comment: Pratik,
Thank you so much! There is one more featured I'm trying to figure out. I need to add dimensions/text data to the featured image on the right. I was going to add it to another image and swap it ... or maybe hide captions with data on the images and show them on the featured? Any thoughts on a best approach for this?

Thanks so much for helping me!

Comment: See your this Question is solved ! :)  .please post the above Query in  next Question ,i will help you for sure!

Comment: Thanks Pratik! Will do.

Comment: +1 ........ Here to me for answer ? Maybe you dont have 15 points ,but   do it if you get 15+ .Thanks

Comment: How do I +1 you? I'd be glad to help.

Comment: upvoting the answer,you can do it if after you have 15 points ,you have 10

Comment: nvm I see it! Once I get +15 I'll up you! THanks!

Comment: post your next Question URL

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the code that puts the original image back

```
    function myFunction() {
    var $large = jQuery('#largeImage');

    //store the default image as the data src
    $large.data('src', $large.attr('src'));

    var src = jQuery('#largeImage').attr('src');
    jQuery('#thumbs img').hover(function () {
        $large.attr('src', jQuery(this).attr('src').replace('thumb', 'large'));
    }, function () {
        //on mouse leave put back the original value
        //$large.attr('src', $large.data('src'));
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(myFunction);
});
```